# CSS layout in Android browser

Tags: android, css, layout, width, break

I'm quite green on CSS but I'm building a webpage and after a lot of searching and coding I've come quite far in browser compability. But there is a big difference in how my Android-phone renders the webpage if you compare to the other major browsers. It looks like this:

http://neobux.se/1.jpg (and 2.jpg)

As you can see, it's slightly better in landscape view. Since the "margin" expands in landscape view I'm guessing it got to have something to do with either my #sidhuvud-vanster-container or #sidhuvud-hoger-container which both have width:50%. View http://viriol.dyndns.org/~elias/ in Firefox/Chrome/IE to see how it SHOULD look like.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

/Elias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to narrow it down in the CSS/HTML today and talk about narrowing down!

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Välkommen till Västkustens Plattsättning!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This HTML with no CSS actually caused the exact same problem in my Android browser. After some more research I finally found my solution. After some research I found out that this is a "bug" in the browser caused by the "Auto-fit" option which is enabled by default.

The solution is to create a transparent GIF/PNG and use as background for h1, h2, h3... and p:

```
h1, h2, h3, p { background: url(../bilder/transparent.gif); }
```

This can be read more about on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100092/p-style-incorrect-unless-background-color-applied) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508889/android-autofit-mode-causing-issues-with-css-width-in-web-page).

Answer (score 0):

---

Here's a rule to live by:  " Left to Right **except** when you're floating "

If you are going to float the *#kontenta-hoger* to the right, then make sure it comes first in your HTML.  ie.

```
<div id="kontenta-hoger">
     <img src="img/img.jpg">
</div>
<div id="kontenta-vanster">
    orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vehicula turpis gravida tellus mattis id pretium diam dictum. Donec eget massa sit amet nulla suscipit ultricies in in justo. Sed lu
</div>
```

Because we need to float the img div to the right.. We put it first in the HTML markup.

You may also consider using percentages for your width's if you'd like to make a basic layout compatible on different resolutions without making it responsive.

Comment: Thanks, this is really good to know. I'm not sure, but I don't think this applies on my page as it's only the img itself thats floated to the right, not the surrounding div. The divs/the page are built using the 960 grid system. Therefore, if I change the order in the HTML markup, the divs will simply change places.